# KEycloak service failed to start

Tags: linux, keycloak, systemctl

I have an issue during the starting of my keycloak linux service.
It's seems that because of the PIDFile definition but it's look like ok because on other VM we have the same service definition and it start fine. You can find bellow the service file definition

```
[Unit]
Description=The Keycloak Server
After=syslog.target network.target
Before=httpd.service

[Service]
Environment=LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/keycloak
User=keycloak
Group=keycloak
LimitNOFILE=102642
PIDFile=/run/keycloak/keycloak.pid
ExecStart=/opt/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh -b $WILDFLY_BIND
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and this is the error in the journalct -xe:

```
mar 22 15:08:32 MYVM sudo[65681]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/myuser ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start keycloak
mar 22 15:08:32 MYVM sudo[65681]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by myuser(uid=0)
mar 22 15:08:32 MYVM systemd[1]: Started keycloak.service - The Keycloak Server.
░░ Subject: L'unité (unit) keycloak.service a terminé son démarrage
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ L'unité (unit) keycloak.service a terminé son démarrage, avec le résultat done.
mar 22 15:08:32 MYVM sudo[65681]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
mar 22 15:08:33 MYVM systemd[1]: keycloak.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit keycloak.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
mar 22 15:08:33 MYVM systemd[1]: keycloak.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ The unit keycloak.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
lines 1706-1760/1760 (END)
```

As you can see the error message dont give a lot of informations